# How to eleminate ASCII characters from Asian language on Youtube with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, youtube-api, ascii

I want to upload a video on Youtube with this title :【最新台】ぱちんこCR北斗の拳５百裂 保留先読み＆ザコビビリ予告 大当たり!!  but Youtube does not allow some ASCII characters such as【 .
 I am using this code to eleminate ASCII characters from my videos

```
string s = "søme string";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);
```

but when I use that code, my title turns to C!!1. I want to use Asian languages for the titles of the videos.

What kind of code should I use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation here: [UnicodeEncoding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It will tell you how to use System.Text to allow C# to handle UTF-16, or other encodings.

As for the WebAPI, I cannot speak from experiance, but I can say that most have an option of the form:

```
encoding=""
```

somewhere. For which you would put in:

```
encoding="UTF-16".
```